# How do you add an UIView over a scroll but the view should stay still?

Tags: iphone, image, view, scroll

iPhone Interface Builder question: Does anybody know how to add a small UIView over a ScrollView yet the image should stay still? Basically I already have a full image (320 x 480) over the Scroll, so the image scrolls, but now I need to add a AdMob View (320 x 48) on top of them. The problem is after i build and run, the ad scrolls as well. How do you make it stay still?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is how you've done it in your code, but if you've added the AdMob view as a subview of the scroller, then it will scroll.

It should not scroll if you add it as a subview elsewhere, either the superview of the scroller or the window itself.

I admit though that I generally do not use Interface Builder and would generally handle this programmatically, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks MG. The question is which one is the superview in this case? the adMob would be on the front page. Or: how do i create a subview? You meant to creat a new view and somehow overlap it? Thanks...sorry, I am confused...

Answer (score 1):

Just place the AdMob view at the same hierarchical level of the ScrollView but being in front. Then when the Ad is available, set adMobView.hidden=NO, when it is not available set adMobView.hidden=YES. Essentially the hierarchy is:

```
RootView -
          |---- UIScrollView
                           |----- any UIView (to be scrolled)
          |---- AdMobView   --> not subview of ScrollView but subview of RootView
```

Of course when the Ad is visible you will not be able to tap on it to scroll, unless you subclass it to pass the tap to next level in hierarchy. But probably you have not this problem thanks to the reduced size of the Ad (48) with respect to the entire scrollView (480).

Comment: You can do it in the Interface Builder, hierarchical view, by just dragging the views in the right positions. So you draw your UIScrollView, then you create the AdMobView, resize and then draw in the hierarchy just below - but outside - the UIScrollView.

Comment: I did that,but the ScrollView is on the whole page. Am I doing something wrong? How do I draw it outside the scroll? Thanks Viggio, sorry for the persistance..

Comment: In IB you need to go to the document window, select the hierarchical view and then drag from the Library the new view and place it in the hierarchy. Yes, resizing it directly from the View window is not easy, so it may help you to change the values directly in the inspector and see the effect. Unfortunately IB doesn't give us the possibility to work with "layers".